# Jsoup Whitelist: Parsing non-english character

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I am trying to clean HTML text and to extract plain text from it using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). The HTML might contain non-english character.

For example the HTML text is:

```
String html = "<p>Á <a href='http://example.com/'><b>example</b></a> link.</p>";
```

Now if I use [`Jsoup#parse(String html)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String text = Jsoup.parse(html).text();
```

It is printing:

```
Á example link.
```

And if I clean the text using [`Jsoup#clean(String bodyHtml, Whitelist whitelist)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Jsoup.html#clean%28java.lang.String,%20org.jsoup.safety.Whitelist%29):

```
String text = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.none());
```

It is printing:

```
&Aacute; example link.
```

My question is, how can I get the text

```
Á example link.
```

using `Whitelist` and `clean()` method? I want to use `Whitelist` since I might be needed to use [`Whitelist#addTags(String... tags)`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html#addTags%28java.lang.String...%29).

Any information will be very helpful to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in current version (1.6.1), jsoup print `Á` as `&Aacute;` because the entity escaping feature, there is no "don't escape" mode now (check `Entities.EscapeMode`).

You can 1. unescape these HTML entities, 2. extend jsoup's source code by adding a new escape mode with an empty map.